# What features differ between the Xbox 360 and PC versions of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console, version-differences

What differences does the Xbox 360 version of Minecraft have compared to playing on the PC?

To clarify - I'm concerned more about the differences exclusive to each platform, not just differences of features that will probably be added in future updates (for example, crafting). Otherwise, I feel this question could be compared to "*What is the difference between Minecraft version x and version y*", which isn't what I'm asking.

Comment: It is pretty significantly behind the PC version, and there's no mods :(  I use it primarily for the split-screen support, and because it's easy to interface with controllers.

Comment: The better question would be what is similar between the two. They are completely separate games that just happen to share a main idea, use similar textures, other resources and some mechanisms. It's like asking what the difference between Super Mario Galaxy and Super Mario Odyssey is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the Minecraft Wiki, the Xbox version is closest to Beta 1.8.2. It is expected to be updated again.

Here are a few key differences between the versions. The full current list can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition#Differences_from_PC_edition).

- Local 4 player split-screen multiplayer (requires HDTV, won't work on SD)
- Limited to 8 player online play (apparently cross platform multi, but not too sure about that)
- Newly designed crafting system

  - Seems to use a list for crafting, so you don't need to remember recipes
- World's limited to 862x862x128 blocks (PC is ∞X∞X256, expected to be increased in later versions)
- Cannot change difficulty mid-game
- Can't use mods, texture packs, or add player skins (8 skins included in game)

  - Texture packs and mods support is expected much later
- Includes tutorial mode
- Kinect support is expected to be added later

**EDIT:**

As of October 12th, 2012, the Xbox version was updated to include all features listed ([here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition_version_history#1.2))

Comment: where did you get the information for the 8 player online play and kinect support?

Comment: @PileOfDuty They were both listed on the [Minecraft wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Xbox_360_Edition). Both items were cited with Tweets by Notch and Jeb, although they don't give much detail on the features.

Comment: Note that the game has been updated to 1.7.3 now, see [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77102/minecraft-xbox-360-1-1-update-details) for details.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few reviews of the new XBox version on YouTube. Here's one from [CaptainSparklez](http://www.youtube.com/user/CaptainSparklez):

It appears that the version used as the basis for the XBox version is pre-[Adventure Update](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Adventure_Update), so it doesn't have a lot of [these newer features](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history/Beta#1.8), like a food system, experience, sprinting, etc.

As far as XBox-specific features that have been added, here's a list of what I've seen so far:

- Nicely polished tutorials, particularly in-game ones.
- A new inventory/crafting UI that includes crafting recipes, so instead of a lot of trial and error to craft things it will tell you what you can make, what you need to make it, and how much of the ingredients you already have.
- Split screen play for up to 4 players.
- A world size limit, so there will be defined edges instead of an endless procedurally-generated map (which would take too much memory). It will still likely be huge, though.

Comment: It's not huge, at least, not if you're used to the PC version.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Minecraft wiki, it is running approximately PC version 1.3.1
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition

Answer (score 1):

Main thing is the screen split. You can play with 4 players in local mode. For now it's the only main difference that I know, you can't play on the xbox live network for now, though Notch said that it will be possible in the future. Except that, there is no major differences "for now". It has just been released so we can wait for upgrades.

Comment: Are you saying that playing online does not work yet? When creating a new game and/or opening up an existing one for playing it showed a checkbox for playing online, but I did not actually test if it worked.

Comment: I don't have the Xbox version, I just read the logs. Maybe it works since I didn't check that version for a while. Tough screen split is present and that's a new feature. I thought xbox live doesn't work right now for minecraft, but I may be wrong ^^

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have all differences, but the big ones:

- [https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition/](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition)
- http://leviathyn.com/blog/2012/04/25/minecraft-pc-vs-xbox-360-2/

The main difference I've found, other than the controls, is the food system. Xbox uses an older version of Minecraft and does not have hunger at all. Xbox also doesn't support the wide array of mods that can be found on the PC version.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since the update in October of 2012 Minecraft is now a 1.7.2 I believe. This update put in hunger, creative, strongholds, abandon mineshafts, host privileges, endermen (ender pearls), silverfish, stonebricks, stained glass, iron bars, and patched a few things. Now what everyone is waiting is blaze so they can beat the game. Another big thing they are waiting on is texture packs and lots of others.

On the other hand pc might have all that but what they don't have would be split screen. Lots of pc players want to have this but they might have to wait because the 360 edition is about 2 years behind in updates. However, Mojang and notch were already behind when it came so the must help the promises they made first to the 360 edition.

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 0):

It does have the 2 by 2 crafting option you press X to open it. But the rest sounded about right and there's much much more that isn't there or doesn't work. One in particular was the ender pearl. I was rather suprized to find that it was available but didn't do anything.

Comment: Welcome to Arquade! Remember that this is a question and answer site, not a forum...so try to make your answers able to stand alone. Once you've got 10 reputation (asking a question that gets just two upvotes or giving an answer that gets just one upvote is enough) you'll be able to leave comments on others' answers. If you see an answer you could improve, there's also the "edit" button, which allows you to suggest an improvement, which will be reviewed by the original author or a high-rep member of the site.

Answer (score -3):

I've read the answers but i have found significant differences. Someone mentioned the "minecraft wiki" which was completely unhelpful to me, given that i can only find a reference page to the 360 version... all other links on it just revert back to PC version.  There are loads of differences.  Here are some that i've experienced (someone please correct me if i'm wrong on any of these):

- no 2x2 crafting option
- far less available objects (iron bars, glass panes, sandstone variances etc.)
- no brewing, enchanting, breeding
- no naturally occurring npc villages in seeds
- i just saw "experience" the 360 doesn't have

Comment: Most of these differences are due to the fact that the XBox version is a port of an older version of Minecraft than the desktop version, which is not what the question is looking for

Comment: Last paragraph is wrong, I'll edit it out. Xbox version is not useless. Maybe to you since you have a good enough computer to run PC version it is, but other people it is very helpful as they get to experience minecraft. Also, it's your fault for buying Xbox version when you already have PC version, you can't complain to Microsoft about that.